# HOW should I go about getting Xubuntu to run a proprietary Windows/Mac browser plugin?

Tags: xubuntu, plugins

I'm exploring bringing Linux into a client's manufacturing environment, and nearly all their production tasks run on a system called Plex Manufacturing Cloud. It supports Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but it requires a proprietary browser plugin, especially when accessing the Zebra label printers they use to track inventory.

Does anyone see a path for me to bring Linux workstations into this environment? Frankly they're too cheap to upgrade a lot of their machines from Win XP so I'm trying to offer them a more secure system.

Comment: Did you try to install that plugin to Ubuntu? Plugins should be multiplatform.

Comment: Depends on whether the plug-in or add-on contains binary code. Can you provide a link to the plug-in/add-on package? I can take a look at it.

Comment: @David Foerster Thanks, it's the per-machine installation [here.](https://www.plexus-online.com/modules/Platform/Login/browserplugin.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser plug-in is incompatible with Linux.

However you can try to install Firefox and its corresponding plug-in in Wine. Printing should work from Wine if the printer is supported by Ubuntu via CUPS.

Alternatively you can set up a virtual machine with Windows and take it from there.

Comment: Thanks David. Going to give it a try in Wine, how would I go about getting that plugin added onto Firefox once I've got the browser set up in Wine (this is about where I've gotten on my test machine).

Comment: The same way you would install any other MSI package in Wine: `wine msiexec /path/to/package.msi`